# Сохранение и загрузка activity

Tags: java, android

Есть два разных activity, условно это home и catalog. Начальной активностью при старте приложения является home. Она подтягивает json строку с параметрами от удаленного сервера, и на его основе генерирует несколько View(изображение и заголовок), а-ля список новостей.

Activity catalog выполняет аналогичный процесс, но с другими данными(и визуально разметка немного отличается).

Вопрос в том, можно ли как то сохранить уже созданные View на activity? Т.е условно я меняю activity через intent, и при возврате обратно хочу загрузить уже "отрисованную" страницу, а не генерировать ее заново. Вариант с сохранением jsona через putExtra уже рассматривал, интересует именно возможность сохранить View, созданные программно

Comment: сохранять именно View - плохая практика от которой следует отказаться. сохранять надо данные, а не их вид на экране. Зачем вы хотите так делать?

Answer (score 0):

Значит логика работы следующая:

Возьмем две активности A и B , и посмотрим на жизненный цикл активностей при переходе из A в B.

Создали A

```
ActivityA: onCreate()
ActivityA: onStart()
ActivityA: onResume()
```

Переходим в B

```
ActivityA: onPause()
ActivityB: onCreate()
ActivityB: onStart()
ActivityB: onResume()
ActivityA: onStop()
```

Мы видим,что активность A не уничтожилась.

Нажимаем кнопку back( переходи из B в A):

```
ActivityB: onPause()
ActivityA: onRestart()
ActivityA: onStart()
ActivityA: onResume()
ActivityB: onStop()
ActivityB: onDestroy()
```

И мы видим что активность A "восстановилась" - миновался вызов onCreate, сразу в onStart.
Тем самым можно сделать вывод,что активность не уничтожиться,а данные сохраняться.И спокойно отобразятся.

Но при переходе в Активность B,у активности A может спокойно вызваться метод onDestroy(например система андроид освободила память), и когда мы перейдем обратно на активность A, то жизненный цикл начентся с onCreate и все данные потеряются.
Как быть - чтобы этого не произошло? Для этого мы должны сохранять данные в методе onSaveInstanceState и получать сохраненный данные в onRestoreInstanceState или в onCreate(во многих кейсах так). Но разметка(views) перерисуются в любом случае.

приведу пример кода где данные восстанавливаются в onCreate :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String VALUE_KEY = "Value";
private int mValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(VALUE_KEY);
    } else {
        mValue = 1;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Value: " + mValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mValue = 2;
    outState.putInt(VALUE_KEY, mValue);
}
```

}

Метод onSaveInstanceState(...) вызывается между onPause() и onStop().

Метод onRestoreInstanceState(...) вызывается после onStart().